# How do you list number of lines of every file in a directory in human readable format.

Tags: bash, awk, python, perl

I have a list of directories and subdirectories that contain large csv files.  There are about 500 million lines in these files, each is a record.  I would like to know

1. How many lines are in each file.
2. How many lines are in directory.
3. How many lines in total

Most importantly, I need this in 'human readable format' eg. 12,345,678 rather than 12345678

It would be nice to learn how to do this in 3 ways. Plain vanilla bash tools, awk etc., and perl (or python).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

> How many lines are in each file.

Use `wc`, originally for word count, I believe, but it can do lines, words, characters, bytes, and the longest line length. The `-l` option tells it to count lines.

```
wc -l <filename>
```

This will output the number of lines in :

```
$ wc -l /dir/file.txt
32724 /dir/file.txt
```

You can also pipe data to `wc` as well:

```
$ cat /dir/file.txt | wc -l
32724
$ curl google.com --silent | wc -l
63
```

> How many lines are in directory.

Try:

```
find . -name '*.pl' | xargs wc -l
```

another one-liner:

```
( find ./ -name '*.pl' -print0 | xargs -0 cat ) | wc -l
```

BTW, `wc` command counts new lines codes, not lines. When last line in the file does not end with new line code, this will not counted.

You may use grep -c ^ , full example:

```
#this example prints line count for all found files
total=0
find /path -type f -name "*.php" | while read FILE; do
     #you see use grep instead wc ! for properly counting
     count=$(grep -c ^ < "$FILE")
     echo "$FILE has $count lines"
     let total=total+count #in bash, you can convert this for another shell
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

> How many lines in total

Not sure that I understood you request correctly. e.g. this will output results in the following format, showing the number of lines for each file:

```
# wc -l `find /path/to/directory/ -type f`
 103 /dir/a.php
 378 /dir/b/c.xml
 132 /dir/d/e.xml
 613 total
```

Alternatively, to output just the total number of new line characters without the file by file counts to following command can prove useful:

```
# find /path/to/directory/ -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END{print total}'
 613
```

> Most importantly, I need this in 'human readable format' eg.
>   12,345,678 rather than 12345678

Bash has a [printf](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) function built in:

```
printf "%0.2f\n" $T
```

As always, there are many different methods that could be used to achieve the same results mentioned here.

Comment: By the way, how do I use printf in your examples?  I tried to pipe to it from wc -l, but it didn't work.

Comment: try  
> find . -name '*.pl' | xargs wc -l | awk '{printf ("%0.2f ", $1) } {print $2}'

change the output of 'printf' for your needs

Comment: This doesn't add commas to the number to make it more human readable though.  It just adds a zeros to the end.

Comment: echo 1000000000000 | xargs printf "%'d\n"
1,000,000,000,000

Comment: this (printf "%'d\n") what I meant by "change the output of 'printf' for your needs" ,)

Comment: @Hexatonic `printf` doesn't read its arguments from `stdin`, but rather from the command line (compare piping to `echo` vs piping to `cat`; `cat` reads from `stdin`, `echo` doesn't). Instead, use `printf "$(find ... | xargs ...)"` to supply the output as arguments to `printf`.

Comment: n.b. xargs is limited to a certain size and thus you can get spurious results. Unfortunately only the GNU wc command takes a stream/file input for file listings. See my answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for files with spaces in the file name.

Comment: Although this was not asked in this question, if someone is looking to list the 5 largest files, I used : `find . -name '*.pl' | xargs wc -l | sort -k1 -n -r | head -n 5`

Answer (score 31):

In many cases combining the `wc` command and the wildcard `*` may be enough.
If all your files are in a single directory you can call:

```
wc -l src/*
```

You can also list several files and directories:

```
wc -l file.txt readme src/* include/*
```

This command will show a list of the files and their number of lines.
The last line will be the sum of the lines from all files.

---

To count all files in a directory recursively:

First, enable globstar by adding `shopt -s globstar` to your .bash_profile.  Support for globstar requires Bash ≥ 4.x which can be installed with `brew install bash` if needed.  You can check your version with `bash --version`.

Then run:

```
wc -l **/*
```

Note that this output will be incorrect if globstar is not enabled.

Comment: And for counting files in the currrent directory recursively: `wc -l **/*`

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston For me (on Mac) that only counts the files exactly one directory down.  It skips the files in the current directory, and for any instance that would be more than one directory deep it warns that it's a directory: "`wc: parent_dir/child_dir: read: Is a directory`"

Comment: @Thomio It requires globstar to be enabled.  On macOS, I believe it is disabled out of the box.  I've just sent an edit to your answer that adds the command and how to enable globstar.

Comment: That is a quality answer.

Answer (score 9):

This command will give list of lines code in each directory:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: On *nix systems file names don't necessarily have a dot `.` in them. This command will find files like `output.txt` and `output.thu.txt` but will not include files with names like `output`. Using `-name *` would work, but then there's no point in using `-name` at all. The command would be `find . -type f | xargs wc -l`

Answer (score 6):

I will just augment @malyy answer for the following (to big for a comment):

> How many lines in total

Many answers are using `wc` command line file option with `xargs`. The problem with this is xargs is limited to a rather small platform dependent size.

Furthermore there is a difference between BSD (macOS) and GNU (linux/homebrew) `wc`.

The GNU one is ideal because it can read the file listing from a file instead of arguments (`--files0`).

If you are on mac and have homebrew you should do the following:

```
find . -name "*.pl" -print0 | gwc -l --files0=-
```

*Notice the gwc instead of wc*.

Comment: Found the above to be effective. Used a slightly different flavor:

`find . -type f -name "*.cs" -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-`

Comment: @NathanAW I found this too reading the man and it works perfectly. I use it to count the total line of code of project.

Answer (score 4):

a bit late to the game, but I got a bunch of argument errors with the above due to the size of the dir.  This worked for me:

`for i in $(find . -type f); do wc -l $i; done >> /home/counts.txt`

Answer (score 2):

`cat` would combine the files into one and outputs everything to stdout, you can do a `wc -l` on that for a total count of lines of files in a directory:

```
cat /path/to/directory/* | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need only total lines from all files use grep

```
find . -name '*.csv' | xargs wc -l | grep total
```

This command works too

```
wc -l *.csv | grep total
```

Comment: (1) This will fail if any filenames contain whitespace or other special characters. (2) While `xargs` is a handy program, it’s not magic. The kernel imposes a limit on how long a command line can be; `xargs` cannot magically exceed that limit. Therefore, if there’s too much input, `xargs` will execute the specified command (``wc -l``, in your example) multiple times. So you could, in theory, get output like `1 file0`, `2 file1`, `4 file2`, `7 total`, `⁠ 8 file3`, `16 file4`, `24 total`. (2b) Worse, if (hypothetically) the command-line limit is so small that `xargs` can handle  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  only 1000 files at a time, and you have 6001 files, then it will run `wc -l` seven times; once for files 1-1000, once for files 1001-2000, etc., … and the seventh run will get just one file: `file6001`.  Since that invocation of `wc` has only one argument, it will not produce a “total” line.  (There’s a simple trick to work around this. Do you know it? Can you think of it?)  (3) Your `grep` will capture files that have “total” in their names.  (4) Like most of the other answers, you have ignored the requirement to insert thousands separators (`,`) every third digit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is very useful!

Answer (score -1):

On the theme of “another way to do it, not necessarily the best way”, how about:

```
find /path/to/directory -name '*' -exec wc {} +
```

This is ok for white space in the filename but still suffers from the “too many files” problem.

Comment: Using `-name '*'` in `find` is pointless. It produces exactly the same list as `find /path/to/directory` — plus your "find" includes directories, causing `Is a directory` errors from wc. _And_ wc without args lists 3 numbers per file; lines, words, and characters.  You want `-type f` on find to get only files without directories, and `-l` on wc to count only lines: `find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +`