# How to count total number of lines of all .txt files?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to get total number of lines from all .txt files. I think the problem is on the line 6 -> `let $((total = total + count ))`. Anybody knows what's to correct form of this?

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
find /home -type f -name "*.txt" | while read -r FILE; do
          count=$(grep -c ^ < "$FILE")
           echo "$FILE has $count lines"
           let $((total = total + count ))
        done
        echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you just want the total, or also the per-file breakdown?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the code in your post, I'm guessing it might be from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260636/409852) post.

While this isn't the *best* way to do this, you can use the following instead:

```bsh
shopt -s lastpipe
total=0
find pathhere -type f -name "*.txt" | while read FILE; do
     count=$(grep -c ^ < "$FILE")
     echo "$FILE has $count lines
     total=$((total + count))
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

or with `wc`:

```bsh
shopt -s lastpipe
total=0
find pathhere -type f -name "*.txt" | while read FILE; do
     count=$(wc -l < "$FILE")
     echo "$FILE has $count lines"
     total=$((total + count))
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

You might have noticed the `shopt -s lastpipe`, and that's [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16854326/12349101) the `while` loop is running in a subshell, and thus doesn't carry over the new value of the variable `total` at the end of the loop...unless you use this option at the top.

Or if you want something faster and shorter:

```bsh
find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END{print total}'
```

Comment: You're welcome :) @OtaŠkvor

Comment: Hmm, don't the first two versions here (with the `while` loops) share the same problem as that in the question: that with Bash `$total` prints as `0` after the loop?

Comment: Right, didn't notice the while loop was in a subshell, which wasn't keeping the result of the `total` variable...thanks for mentioning, will edit @ilkkachu

Answer (score 20):

Your line 6 is better written as

```bsh
total=$(( total + count ))
```

... but it would be better still to use a tool that is *made* for counting lines (assuming you want to count newlines, i.e. the number of properly terminated lines)

```bsh
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

This finds all regular files in or below the current directory that have filenames ending in `.txt`.  All these files are concatenated into a single stream and piped to `wc -l`, which outputs the total number of lines, which is what the title and text of the question asks for.

Complete script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

nlines=$( find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l )

printf 'Total number of lines: %d\n' "$nlines"
```

To also get the individual files' line count, consider

```bsh
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sh -c '
    wc -l "$@" |
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        sed "\$d"
    else
        cat
    fi' sh {} + |
awk '{ tot += $1 } END { printf "Total: %d\n", tot }; 1'
```

This calls `wc -l` on batches of files, outputting the line cound for each individual file.  When `wc -l` is called with more than one filename, it will output a line at the end with the total count.  We delete this line with `sed` if the in-line `sh -c` script is called with more than one filename argument.

The long list of line counts and file pathnames is then passed to `awk`, which simply adds the counts up (and passes the data through) and presents the user with the total count at the end.

---

On GNU systems, the `wc` tool can read pathnames from a nul-delimited stream. You can use that with `find` and its `-print0` action on these systems like so:

```bsh
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 |
wc --files0-from=- -l
```

Here, the found pathnames are passed as a  nul-delimited list over the pipe to `wc` using the non-standard `-print0`. The `wc` utility is used with the non-standard `--files0-from` option to read the list being passed across the pipe.

Comment: Why all this complexity? Wouldn't `shopt -s globstar; wc -l **/*.txt` be enough?

Comment: `-exec cat {} +` the `+` is subtle but brilliant. had to read the manpage to figure out what it does and learned something new. thanks!

Comment: @user000001 Yes of course, if you can _guarantee_ that `**/*.txt` expands to a list that is short enough to not trigger an "argument list too long " error.  You can't do that in the general case, and the user in the question does not indicate the number of files involved.

Answer (score 6):

```
let $((total = total + count ))
```

This works, but is a bit redundant, since both `let` and `$(( .. ))` start arithmetic expansion.

Any of `let "total = total + count"`, `let "total += count"`, `: $((total = total + count))` or `total=$((total + count))` would do it without the duplication. The last two should be compatible with a standard shell, `let` isn't.

```
total=0
find /home -type f -name "*.txt" | while read -r FILE; do
    total=...
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

You didn't say what problem you mean, but one problem you have here is that in Bash, the parts of a pipeline run in subshells by default, so any changes made to `total` inside the `while` loop are not visible after it. See: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373)

You could use `shopt -s lastpipe` to have the last part of the pipeline run in the shell; or group the `while` and `echo`:

```
find ... | { while ...
    done; echo "$total"; }
```

---

Of course, `find ... | while read -r FILE;` will have problems with filenames that contain newlines, or start/end with whitespace. You could fix that with

```
find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE; do ...
```

or, if you don't care about the breakdown of per-file line counts and know your files are complete text files, with none missing the final newline, you could simply concatenate all the files together and run `wc -l` on that.

If your files may be missing the newline at the end of the last line, and you want to count that final incomplete line, then you can't do that, and need to keep using `grep -c ^` instead of `wc -l`. (Counting the final partial line is pretty much the only reason to use `grep -c ^` instead of `wc -l`.)

See: [What's the point in adding a new line to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743/170373) and [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/6372809) on SO.

Also, if you only want the total count, all the files matching the pattern are regular files (so the `-type f` test can be dropped), and you have Bash and GNU grep, you could also do:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
grep -h -c ^ **/*.txt | awk '{ a += $0 } END { print a }'
```

`**/*.txt` is a recursive glob, it needs to be explicitly enabled to work. `dotglob` makes that glob also match filenames starting with a dot. `grep -h` suppresses the filenames from the output, and the `awk` script counts the sum. Since no filenames are printed, this should work even if some of them a problematic.

Or, as suggested by @fra-san, based on another now-deleted answer:

```
grep -r -c -h --include='*.sh' ^ |awk '{ a+= $0 } END {print a }'
```

Comment: didn't thought you could `group the while and the echo` like this, Nice :)

Answer (score 5):

`let total+=count` will work, there's no need for `$(( ))` with this form of arithmetic evaluation.

But you'd be much better off doing this with `wc -l`.

```
find /home -type f -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} +
```

If you want custom output as in your shell script above, OR if there are likely to be more filenames than will fit in the ~2MB line-length limit of bash on linux, you could use `awk` or `perl` to do the counting.  Anything is better than a shell while-read loop (see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696)).  For example:

```
find /home -type f -name '*.txt' -exec perl -lne '
  $files{$ARGV}++;

  END {
    foreach (sort keys %files) {
      printf "%s has %s lines\n", $_, $files{$_};
      $total+=$files{$_}
    };
    printf "TOTAL LINES COUNTED: %s\n", $total
  }' {} +
```

Note: the `find ... -exec perl` command above will ignore empty files, whereas the `wc -l` version would list them with a line count of 0.  It's possible to make perl do the same (see below).

OTOH, it will do a line count and total for **any** number of files, even if they won't all fit in one shell command line - the `wc -l` version would print **two** or more `total` lines in that case - probably not going to happen, but not what you want if it did.

This should work, this uses `wc -l` and pipes the output into perl to change it to the desired output format:

```
$ find /home -type f -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} + |
    perl -lne 'next if m/^\s+\d+\s+total$/;
               s/\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/$2 has $1 lines/;
               print;
               $total += $1;

               END { print "TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total"}'
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the `+` after `{}`?

Comment: When using find's `-exec` option, the `{}` is a placeholder for the found files.  Ending the `-exec` with a semi-colon `;` (which has to be escaped as `\;` in the shell) makes find execute the command once for each filename.   Ending it with `+` makes find try to fit as many filenames on the command as it can (current cmd line length limit on linux is about 2 million characters - a lot of filenames).   i.e. the `+` makes find run `wc -l file1 file2 file3 ...... fileN` instead of `wc -l file1` then `wc -l file2` and so on until `wc -l fileN`.

Comment: Ah, I see. (I had looked at the `find` manual page but searched for an unescaped `+` which does something different in less).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading every line, which isn't very optimal, use [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc).
Also correct arithmetic evaluation syntax: `total=$((total+count))` would help.

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
path=/home

for f in $(find $path -type f -name "*.txt"); do
    count=$(wc -l < $f)
    echo "$FILE has $count lines"
    total=$((total + count))
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

This doesn't work with filenames with spaces or new lines.
Buyer beware.

Comment: Related to your loop over the output of `find`: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Well, yes, you're right. I'm going to add stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export total=$(find . -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l "{}" ";" | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$1} END{print sum}')
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED ${total}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are all in one directory then this works:

```
cat -- *.txt | wc -l
```

(note: it doesn't count hidden files such as `.foo.txt` unless you enabled the `dotglob` or `globdots` option of your shell)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Adapting the excellent (first) Perl5 answer from @cas here:*

```perl
~$ find ~/find_dir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec raku -ne '
   BEGIN my %files; state $total;
  
         %files{$*ARGFILES}++;

   END   for (sort keys %files) {
         printf "%s has %s lines\n", $_, %files{$_};
         $total+=%files{$_};

   LAST  printf "TOTAL LINES COUNTED: %s\n", $total
         }' {} +
```

Significant differences between the original Perl5 code and this Raku code include invariant sigils--specifically the hash `%files` never changes sigils. In Raku, files read off the command line are found in the `$*ARGFILES` dynamic variable, although for more complicated scripts the `@*ARGS` array can be used. Raku also has a series of Control Flow commands including `BEGIN`, `END`, and `LAST` which are put to good use here.

Starting anew in Raku, I would probably write something like the following, which takes advantage of Raku's `dir(…)` routine:

```perl
~$ raku -e '
   my  $total;
  
   for dir("$*CWD/file_dir", test => /\.txt$/ ) -> $name {
       my  $lc = $name.lines.elems; 
       say $name.absolute => $lc; 
       $total += $lc; 
   };
 
   say "TOTAL LINES COUNTED: $total";'
```

Because Raku's `dir(…)` routine can test/filter by a literal string (e.g. `test => ".txt"`), OR a regex matcher (e.g. `test => /\.txt$/` ), the programmer does not have to rely on shell-globbing to ***filter-in*** only the `.txt` files-of-interest.

The code above returns stringified `IO::PATH` => `$lc` pairs giving the number of lines as `value`. The `absolute` method call resolves paths. It's simple enough to append these pairs into a hash (if necessary) for further manipulations. As above, the total lines (`$total`) are also output in the last statement.

https://docs.raku.org/language/control.html
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://docs.raku.org/language/io-guide#Stringifying_IO::Path
https://raku.org